# Is there any way I can avoid pagination in legends of a google visualisation chart and show all the lines in two lines in a single page?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am currently using a google visualisation pie chart. The legends of the chart needs to be showed at the bottom and in a single page, not in a paginated way.I searched in google visualisation api pages and properties but couldn't find a way to remove the pagination and show all legend in two lines without pagination. There is space for showing legends in two line, but dont know why google is showing it in a paginated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done. The google visualisation API doesn't provide any ways of avoiding the pagination. The only way is to resize the chart and reduce the legend font. All the legends are shown in a single page if the position is left/right.